# Logging in via G+ API doesn't log user into the correct account on YouTube

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, google-plus

**SEE [THIS VIDEO](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94123/bigframe/login_like_video_in_player.mov) FOR A SCREEN CAPTURE OF THE ISSUE**

I'm currently letting user's authenticate via the G+ JavaScript API, `gapi.auth.signIn` method. When logging into an account that is connected to a G+ profile, I am presented with the delegate account selector, which allows me to choose either my email address account or the linked G+ profile account.

After I select an account, I make an API request within the `signinCallback` method to retrieve the user's image and displayName, which return the correct account (in this case, the G+ account). I also load the player API within the `signinCallback` method. The player API then calls it's own `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` callback method, where I load a video:

```
player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
  height: '390',
  width: '640',
  videoId: 'nda_OSWeyn8',
  playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1}
});
```

If I 'like' the video from within the player, the like is recorded on my regular YouTube account, NOT the linked G+ YouTube account that I selected from the delegated selector.

Is there a way to force the embedded player to load with the correct user (G+ account)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's web sessions and application tokens are different. Web sessions a controlled by the dropdown you show on youtube in the video and not by the account chooser in the application authentication flow. Authenticating a application will not change the current web session account beyond making additional accounts available if you login during the flow.

Comment: Why then, when I'm logged out of Youtube and authenticate via my app and choose my G+ account in the delegate, it logs me into YouTube, but not as the account I chose in the delegate selector? It's an odd experience that I choose a linked account, but it doesn't set the account on YouTube and I have to choose it again.

Comment: When signing into Google, they generally just sign into the actual account and not a sub identity. If you think that's confusing you'll have to send feedback to Google.

Comment: If Google is going to prompt for the sub identity, then it would make sense to also select that on other Google properties where available. Otherwise, just authenticating against the main account would make more sense. I'll just have to open a request and hope for the best.